# Is there a way to determine what code is bloating a linux shared object?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

Built a release linux shared object which has a size of 28MB

```
28681504 Feb  6 19:46 libmtcrypto.so
```

It was created using this partial command including openssl, boost and numerous other libraries

```
/usr/bin/c++ -fPIC -O2 -g -DNDEBUG -shared -Wl,-soname,libmtcrypto.so -o lib/libmtcrypto.so ...
```

Such a large sized binary has people asking "why so large for a simple shared object that exports only one function?"

My suspicion is that it's these openssl archives (42MB and 7MB)

[image: bloat]

**Question**

Is there way to determine which code library is bloating the shared object?

**Update**

Based upon the comments, it seems related to ALL symbols and debug info being added. I ran the suggested command:

```
strip libmtcrypto.so
```

and it reduced the shared object from 28MB to 5MB!

```
5634592 Feb  6 20:25 libmtcrypto.so*
```

The build system is adding the `-g` option so I'll contact those people to remove it from the release builds.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you build a smaller shared library that has only the code you use?

Comment: You could inspect the symbols. Your library should only expose symbols that are part of the public API. You build this with `-g`. Do you _want_ debug symbols in there?

Comment: I'll try reducing the project to a simple example. It uses RSA, AES-CBC via EVP openssl functions. Was hoping there was some kind of build process file artifact or a linux command line tool which would show the various regions of the shared object. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `strip` to strip out all non-dynamic symbols and see how that affects the file size. Note that this will modify the file in place. If you want to hang on to the original large binary, make a copy first.

Comment: To reduce size, do not produce debugging information [-g](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-g) and strip the symbol table with the parameter [`-s`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-12.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#index-s).

Comment: You may be inadvertently exporting all symbols -- even the ones of the archives you include. Are you setting the default visibility to "hidden", and then marking only the symbols that are part of your public API as "visible"?

Comment: And for the love of god, make sure you don't include the public header files of libcrypto and libssl in your library's public header files!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way to determine which code library is bloating the shared object?

Yes, there is a tool for exactly this analysis: [Bloaty McBloatface: a size profiler for binaries](https://github.com/google/bloaty).

It's very likely due to all the debug info. Running

```
strip -g libmtcrypto.so -o libmtcrypto-stripped.so
ls -l libmtcrypto-stripped.so
```

will readily prove (of disprove) this guess.